# spring boot not using the MongoDB uri in the application.properties

Tags: java, mongodb, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

In my **Spring-boot application**, I was trying to use **MongoDB** which is in **AWS instance**. For that, I used the **host and port number of the AWS Instance** to connect it through Spring-boot

*application.properties*

```
server.port=8186

# MONGODB (MongoProperties)
#spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
#spring.data.mongodb.port=27018 
#spring.data.mongodb.database=educharge

spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://52.15.64.17:27017/educharge
spring.data.mongodb.database=educharge
```

when I run the application the program connect to **localhost** instead of **host(  52.15.64.17)**

Console output

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.6.RELEASE)

2017-09-16 03:10:08.402  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] c.E.E.EduchargeApiApplication            : Starting EduchargeApiApplication on Sankar with PID 9536 (G:\EduchargeAPI\EduchargeAPI\bin started by R Dinesh Kumar in G:\EduchargeAPI\EduchargeAPI)
2017-09-16 03:10:08.402  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] c.E.E.EduchargeApiApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-09-16 03:10:08.408  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@53b63b22: startup date [Sat Sep 16 03:10:08 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-09-16 03:10:09.716  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8186 (http)
2017-09-16 03:10:09.718  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-09-16 03:10:09.718  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.16
2017-09-16 03:10:09.750  INFO 9536 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-09-16 03:10:09.750  INFO 9536 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1342 ms
2017-09-16 03:10:09.816  INFO 9536 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-09-16 03:10:09.826  INFO 9536 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'metricsFilter' to: [/*]
2017-09-16 03:10:09.827  INFO 9536 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-09-16 03:10:09.827  INFO 9536 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-09-16 03:10:09.827  INFO 9536 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-09-16 03:10:09.827  INFO 9536 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-09-16 03:10:09.827  INFO 9536 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-09-16 03:10:09.827  INFO 9536 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
2017-09-16 03:10:09.866  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=50}
2017-09-16 03:10:10.071  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@53b63b22: startup date [Sat Sep 16 03:10:08 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-09-16 03:10:10.088  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/Posts/showPost/{postid}],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Model.Post com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Controller.PostController.showPost(int)
2017-09-16 03:10:10.089  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/Posts/{postid}/like/{userid}],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Model.Post com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Controller.PostController.likePost(int,int)
2017-09-16 03:10:10.090  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/Posts/editPost],methods=[PUT]}" onto public com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Model.Post com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Controller.PostController.editPost(com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Model.Post)
2017-09-16 03:10:10.090  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/Posts/{postid}/comment/{userid}],methods=[PUT]}" onto public com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Model.Post com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Controller.PostController.commentPost(java.lang.String,int,int)
2017-09-16 03:10:10.090  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/Posts/createPost],methods=[POST]}" onto public com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Model.Post com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Controller.PostController.createPost(com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Model.Post)
2017-09-16 03:10:10.090  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/Posts/deletePost/{postid}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Model.Post com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Controller.PostController.deletePost(int)
2017-09-16 03:10:10.091  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/Posts/{postid}/dislike/{userid}],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Model.Post com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Controller.PostController.dislikePost(int,int)
2017-09-16 03:10:10.096  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/Profiles/showProfile/{userid}],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Model.Profile com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Controller.ProfileController.showProfile(int)
2017-09-16 03:10:10.097  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/Profiles/createProfile],methods=[POST]}" onto public com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Model.Profile com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Controller.ProfileController.addProfile(com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Model.Profile)
2017-09-16 03:10:10.097  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/Profiles/editProfile],methods=[PUT]}" onto public com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Model.Profile com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Controller.ProfileController.editProfile(com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Model.Profile)
2017-09-16 03:10:10.097  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/Profiles/deleteProfile/{userid}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Model.Profile com.Educharge.EduchargeAPI.Controller.ProfileController.deleteProfile(int)
2017-09-16 03:10:10.101  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-09-16 03:10:10.102  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-09-16 03:10:10.118  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-09-16 03:10:10.118  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-09-16 03:10:10.141  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-09-16 03:10:10.319  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/info || /info.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-09-16 03:10:10.321  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/heapdump || /heapdump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/octet-stream]}" onto public void org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HeapdumpMvcEndpoint.invoke(boolean,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException,javax.servlet.ServletException
2017-09-16 03:10:10.322  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/mappings || /mappings.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-09-16 03:10:10.323  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/configprops || /configprops.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-09-16 03:10:10.324  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2017-09-16 03:10:10.324  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics || /metrics.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-09-16 03:10:10.325  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/beans || /beans.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-09-16 03:10:10.325  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/dump || /dump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-09-16 03:10:10.326  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/health || /health.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.security.Principal)
2017-09-16 03:10:10.329  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/auditevents || /auditevents.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.AuditEventsMvcEndpoint.findByPrincipalAndAfterAndType(java.lang.String,java.util.Date,java.lang.String)
2017-09-16 03:10:10.330  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2017-09-16 03:10:10.330  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env || /env.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-09-16 03:10:10.332  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/loggers/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LoggersMvcEndpoint.get(java.lang.String)
2017-09-16 03:10:10.333  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/loggers/{name:.*}],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LoggersMvcEndpoint.set(java.lang.String,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2017-09-16 03:10:10.333  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/loggers || /loggers.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-09-16 03:10:10.334  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/trace || /trace.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-09-16 03:10:10.336  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/autoconfig || /autoconfig.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-09-16 03:10:10.367  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2017-09-16 03:10:10.434  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-09-16 03:10:10.443  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2017-09-16 03:10:10.499  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8186 (http)
2017-09-16 03:10:10.501  INFO 9536 --- [  restartedMain] c.E.E.EduchargeApiApplication            : Started EduchargeApiApplication in 2.166 seconds (JVM running for 4203.36)
2017-09-16 03:10:10.873  INFO 9536 --- [127.0.0.1:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 127.0.0.1:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

and prints the **Exception opening socket**

**Is there any other way to connect the remote MongoDB host server ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are connecting to your remote Mongodb instance, have you checked `52.15.64.17` is pingable for you?

Based on  [Connecting to a MongoDB database](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connecting-to-mongodb):

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:secret@mongo1.example.com:12345,mongo2.example.com:23456/test
```

Alternatively, You can mute the Springboot AutoConfiguration for mongoDB:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: Yes Sir, It was  responding when I tried to connect using MongoDB client

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem using MongoDB and Embedded MongoDB, each one configured in a different spring profile.

In my case, the Spring was ignoring the MongoDB URI from my "production" profile and it always started the embedded mongoDb.

The problem was the `EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration` enabled. So, you can disable the Embedded MongoDB in a specific profile using the properties:

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration
```